# atom libc-2.31.so segfault in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault, atom-editor, libc

[atom](https://atom.io/) worked smoothly in my Dell Latitude 5410 running Ubuntu 18.04. Suddenly it won't open and looking at `tail -F /var/log/syslog` I got a `libc-2.31.so` segfault:

```sh
Jan 15 03:22:17 enrico-dell-latitude-5410 kernel: [ 1719.307314] atom[6202]: segfault at 1 ip 00007f98b04ec7b8 sp 00007fff83d94e68 error 6 in libc-2.31.so[7f98b0383000+178000]
```

Does anybody got a clue about how to solve this and/or investigate this segfault deeper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue on a HP computer running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

**EDIT:** I do not currently have enough reputation to comment or upvote, but the comment from @zesaver helped me. I did the following:

1. Remove Atom using snap

```
$ sudo snap remove atom
```

2. Go [on the Atom tutorial page](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/) section **Installing Atom on Linux** subsection **Debian and Ubuntu (deb/apt)** , follow the instructions, namely

```
$ wget -qO - https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install atom
```

And it works !

Answer (score 1):

Same on ThinkPad running Ubuntu 18.04.02.

Resolved (kind-of) with removing the snap package

`sudo snap remove snap`

and installing from packagecloud.io (via instruction at https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/).